# what is this vraimax and vraimin?

Tags: functional-analysis, notation

I see this notation used in Linear and Quasilinear Equations of Parabolic Type, but it is not explained in the notation table

Moreover, it defines osc as the difference between the two.

I am guessing it means something like supremum  or essential supremum but I am not 100% sure so I want to check this.

Comment: maybe relevant [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=yfPiBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA267&lpg=PA267).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\operatorname{vrai\, max} u$ denotes the essential supremum of $u$, the notation uses the French word *vrai* (true, essential) instead of the English *essential*. See for example in Yosida's *Functional Analysis*, p. 34.

Comment: so what is vraimin?

Comment: It is the essential infimum.