# what does "vral max" mean?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

In the book "linear and quasi-linear equations of parabolic type", what does "vral max" mean?
[image]

Comment: The "vrai max" (not "vral", actually the $l$ is an $i$ with the dot on top poorly rendered) is the Russian (semi?)translation of the *essential supremum*.

Comment: French origin : "vrai" means "true"...

Comment: What would be the nuance between "max" & "vral/vrai/true max" ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_infimum_and_essential_supremum

Comment: @Prem The "essential" supremum/vrai max or maximum ignores "small sets where a function may behave weirdly" (formally, sets of measure zero). To give an example, if $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ is defined as $f(0)=1$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x\in (0,1]$, then the supremum of $f$ is $f(0)=1$ but the essential supremum/vrai max ignores that one point and it turns out that the essential supremum of $f$ is $0$.

Comment: Interesting Point , thank you , @SarveshRavichandranIyer & JAAP , for sharing the measure theory background. The typesetting in that textbook looks weird like $ vrai [ max [ \cdots ] ] $ ( due to the Condition given below only "max" ) when it should be $ vrai\ max [ \cdots ] $ ( with the Condition spread out below "vrai max" ) , though that might be the historically standard way to write it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1927751/what-is-this-vraimax-and-vraimin